# Where should be Android Helper Activity and its layout located

Tags: android, android-layout, code-structure

I am new to android and java, so please excuse me for this silly question.

I have an activity in my project that can be used in many other projects so I would prefer to keep its code separate (maybe in some other package) from everything else in my project.

I have these files

```
MyHelperActivity
my_helper_layout
```

I have no idea how to place them in my project.
currently `MyHelperActivity` is in `mypackage.helper` and `my_helper_layout` is in layout folder of the project and I have included the activity in manifest file.

What should be the folder structure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new project and define it as a library project. then, when you create a new project which need your activity, you simply add it to your build path.

Comment: but I just have one activity.. is it the only way?

Comment: if you want to reuse it in other projects, then yes

Comment: That is really annoying.. creating new project for every little thingy

Comment: you can have only one library project which will contain reusable components.